# How do I test a Component that uses a StaticQuery with Jest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, gatsby

I am trying to create tests for components I have built in a Gatsby based site and am running into a bit of trouble. The component is as follows (based off of the Gatsby docs found here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/testing-components-with-graphql/#testing-staticquery):

```
   export const PureLayout = ({ children, data }) => {
      console.log({ children })
      console.log({ data })
      return (
        <div>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <Helmet
            title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
            meta={[`enter code here`
              {
                name: 'description',
                content:
                  'The portfolio and blog of Chris Kujawa, a full-stack web developer specializing in creating blazingly fast e-commerce sites with Gatsby and React JS.',
              },
              {
                name: 'keywords',
                content:
                  'web development, web developer, ecommerce development, ecommerce website design, ecommerce website development, ecommerce website developer, ecommerce website, custom ecommerce website, GatsbyJS, GatsbyJS Development, GatsbyJS website, Gatsby ecommerce, ReactJS, React developer',
              },
            ]}
          >
            <html lang="en" />
          </Helmet>
          <Header />
          <ChildContainer>{children}</ChildContainer>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )
    }

    export const Layout = props => (
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query SiteTitleQuery {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => <PureLayout {...props} data={data} />}
      />
```

And the test looks like this:

```
describe('Layout', () => {
  it('renders_correctly', () => {
    const data = {
      site: {
        siteMetadata: {
          title: 'Test Site Title',
        },
      },
    }
    const tree = renderer
      .create(
        <Layout data={data}>
          <p>test</p>
        </Layout>
      )
      .toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

What am I missing here? I've ran this through a debugger several times and it looks as though props are being passed into the component correctly.

Thank you for your help/insight!

The component renders just fine in a browser, but when I run the test I get the following error:

> mockConstructor(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually
>   means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return
>   null.
>
> ```
>   14 |     }
>   15 |     const tree = renderer
> > 16 |       .create(
>      |        ^
>   17 |         <Layout data={data}>
>   18 |           <p>test</p>
>   19 |         </Layout>
>
>   at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5097:23)
>   at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7234:28)
>   at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7968:5)
>   at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9019:16)
>   at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12649:12)
>   at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12622:22)
>   at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12333:9)
>   at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1825:24
>   at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
>   at runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1775:10)
>   at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1820:7)
>   at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1808:3)
>   at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11776:9)
>   at updateContainer (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14747:3)
>   at Object.create (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15455:5)
>   at Object.it (src/__tests__/layout.js:16:8)
> ```

Comment: Did you make sure to follow Gatsby's testing set up as described in the [Unit Testing guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/unit-testing/)? There are quite a few steps to go through to make sure your repo has the right mocks and Jest setup before you can start running Jest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went back to the docs to dig and make sure that I followed them as well as I though I had based on Robin's comment above. While digging, I discovered that instead of testing the Layout component, I needed to test the PureLayout directly. The end result is that changing this:

```
import { Layout } from '../components/layout'
```

to this:

```
import { PureLayout as Layout } from '../components/layout'
```

fixes the test so that it now passes. Hope this helps someone else in the future!